# Exporting with QPackage or QConsolidate

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, export, grouping, layer-package

I know there is a similar question, but it might be dated, and didn't completely answer my question.

I know of two plugins to export your QGis project, QPackage and QConsolidate. I'm not very familiar with either. The lather isn't available in the plug-in space in QGIS either, so that makes it a bit more complicated. But what I need:

- to export all my layers, with multiple source files over multiple maps
- if possible, save the styles as well at the same time
- layers are grouped like this:

*Project area 1*

- **Work area 1**

  - Coupe
  - Put
  - Vondst
- **Work area 2**

  - Coupe
  - Put
  - Vondst

*Project area 2*

- **Work area 1**

  - Coupe
  - Put
  - Vondst

etc.

So I have layers that have the same name, but fall in a different group/subgroup. I want to export all this at the same time. But I think i'll lose the layer relations (where they are placed in a group), and think the name similarities will give problems with file names.

Is what I want possible with the plugins? Or should I just export everything by itself?

**Edit:**
So far I've renamed all my layers so they have unique names.

With QConsolidate the layers don't gert exported, just the .qgs, so no luck there.

With QPackage everything gets exported, but i do get a warning messege, though I don't know what for. The only thing going wrong there is that the connections with the source file get broken when I move the folder. And since the .qgs is copied entirely it also shows the layers I dindn't export. But the plusside is that the styles get saved as well. So I think reaconnecting the layers with the exported files should do the trick.
This is all very time consuming though, so I still hope someone knows a faster way.

Comment: `QConsolidate` became `QConsolidate3`, and you need to check `Show also experimental plugins` from the `Plugins Setting`, in order to see the plugin.

Comment: Oh thank you. Do you know if the Consolidate3 plugin exports the way I need it to?

Comment: I don't know, but you can give it a try, and see by yourself.

Comment: I tried to use Consolidate, but it didn't export my layers, only the .qgs